# Why does the identityHashCode function not work for the built-in type 'int' in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, class, object, hashcode

The documentation of the identityHashCode says:
[image: documentation]

And it indeed works for my custom type 'Integer':

```
class Integer {
  int num;
  Integer(this.num);

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return num;
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if(other is Integer && this.num == other.num) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}

void main() {
  Integer n1 = Integer(1);
  print(n1.hashCode); // print "1"
  print(identityHashCode(n1)); // print "650939380", a different value!
}
```

But for the built-in type 'int', `identityHashCode(int)` seems to always return the same value as `int.hashCode`, which is the numerical value itself:

```
void main() {
  int n = 1;
  print(n.hashCode); // print "1"
  print(identityHashCode(n)); // still print "1", the same value as n.hashCode!
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening? I'm confused now.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is [Built-in type](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#numbers) (not a usual class)

In documentation `identityHashCode` has a note:

> This hash code is compatible with [identical], which just means that
> it's guaranteed to be stable over time.

For compiler all `int` values are constants. `identical` for the same constants shows true. So `hashCode` of `int` was made by own value (which also `int`).

```
print(identical(1, 1)); // true
```

According to [this comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/563#issuecomment-108304500) `int` (and `double`) has own condition for comparing in `identical` function.

> By the same numeric value

Here's some code for example representation:

```
void main() {
  int a = 1; // '1' is a constant
  int b = 1;
  int c = 2; // '2' is a constant

  print(identical(a, b)); // true
  print(identical(a, c)); // false
  print(identical(1, 1)); // true
  print(identical(1, 2)); // false <= 1 and 2 are constants
  print(identical(a, 1)); // true
  print(identical(c, 1)); // false
  print(identical(c, 2)); // true

  print(identityHashCode(a)); // 1
  print(identityHashCode(b)); // 1
  print(identityHashCode(c)); // 2
  print(identityHashCode(1)); // 1
  print(identityHashCode(2)); // 2
}
```